# Why does overloading the main method give a syntax error?

Tags: java, overloading

```
import java.util.*;
public class Overload {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        System.out.println("in main 1");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("in main 2");
    }
}
```

I was checking if both the main methods have standard signature which one will get executed but when I compile it, it shows error. why is it so?

Comment: How is this duplicate of [Can there exist two main methods in a Java program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399836/can-there-exist-two-main-methods-in-a-java-program). This question asks that `main(String...args)` consists of `varargs` whereas `main(String args[])` consists of `array` as parameter. Both have different signature (if we don't consider compile time conversions), then why we can't define both. Whereas the question *Can there exist two main methods in a Java program?* asks whether a question can have multiple entry points. Both are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an ellipsis (`...`) is just syntactic sugaring that allows you to pass several comma-delimited arguments instead of explicitly declaring an array. From within the method, for all intents and purposes that argument is an array. So, you're essentially defining two methods with the same signature (`public static void main(String[])`), which is not allowed, regardless of the fact that it's the special `main` method.

Answer (score 3):

Varargs are basically compiled into single array. Hence, you have 2 methods which are the same

Your code (changed one of the main, it's now a valid code):

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Overload {
  public static void main2(String... paramVarArgs) {
    System.out.println("in main 1");
  }

  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString) {
    System.out.println("in main 2");
  }
}
```

This code compiled, and decompiled with a bytcode viewer:

```
public class Overload {

     public Overload() { // <init> //()V
         L1 {
             aload0 // reference to self
             invokespecial java/lang/Object <init>(()V);
             return
         }
     }

     public static varargs main2(java.lang.String[] arg0) { //([Ljava/lang/String;)V
         L1 {
             getstatic java/lang/System.out:java.io.PrintStream
             ldc "in main 1" (java.lang.String)
             invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream println((Ljava/lang/String;)V);
         }
         L2 {
             return
         }
     }

     public static main(java.lang.String[] arg0) { //([Ljava/lang/String;)V
         L1 {
             getstatic java/lang/System.out:java.io.PrintStream
             ldc "in main 2" (java.lang.String)
             invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream println((Ljava/lang/String;)V);
         }
         L2 {
             return
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Well, technically, `main()` and `main2()` are **completely different functions**. So doesn't it eliminate the term **overloading** from being applicable here? Plus, if this is the solution, then should we draw the conclusion that _the main method cannot be overloaded_?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot declare both main(String[]) and main(String...). Your class cannot have 2 main methods with same signatue (String...) is same as that of (String[]) . It is not allowed in java.