# the main method overlap in the java program

Tags: java

This is the full coding. Once we compile it |it throwing error that main method already defined before.How to settle this error. Guidance needed. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
import java.math.*;

public class AdditiveCipher {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String message, encryptedMessage = "", decryptedMessage = "", decryptMessage = "", encryptMessage = "";
        String text;
        int key;
        String keyy = "15";
        char ch;
        char cha;

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("-------------------Additive Cipher----------------------");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a message: ");
        message = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter key: ");
        key = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); ++i){
            ch = message.charAt(i);

            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                ch = (char)(ch + key);

                if(ch > 'z'){
                    ch = (char)(ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1);
                }

                encryptedMessage += ch;
            }
            else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                ch = (char)(ch + key);

                if(ch > 'Z'){
                    ch = (char)(ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1);
                }

                encryptedMessage += ch;
            }
            else {
                encryptedMessage += ch;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Encrypted Message using additive cipher = " + encryptedMessage);



//Additive decrypted codes


            Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter a encryted message: ");
            text = sca.nextLine();



            for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i){
                ch = text.charAt(i);

                if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                    ch = (char)(ch - key);

                    if(ch < 'a'){
                        ch = (char)(ch + 'z' - 'a' + 1);
                    }

                    decryptedMessage += ch;
                }
                else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                    ch = (char)(ch - key);

                    if(ch < 'A'){
                        ch = (char)(ch + 'Z' - 'A' + 1);
                    }

                    decryptedMessage += ch;
                }
                else {
                    decryptedMessage += ch;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Decrypted Message using additive cipher = " + decryptedMessage);



    }


//Autokey encrypted codes

    private static String alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String keyy = "15";  //15 - P
        String textt = "HELLO";

    if(keyy.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+"))
         keyy = ""+alpha.charAt(Integer.parseInt(keyy));

        System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("-------------------Autokey Cipher----------------------");
                System.out.println("");

                String enc = AutoEncryption(textt,keyy);
                System.out.println("Enter a encryted message: " +textt);
                System.out.println("Encrypted Message using additive cipher = " + enc);

    }
        public static String AutoEncryption(String textt,String keyy){
        int len = textt.length();

             String subkey = keyy + textt;
             subkey = subkey.substring(0,subkey.length()-keyy.length());

                String sb = "";
                 for(int x=0;x<len;x++){
                         int get1 = alpha.indexOf(textt.charAt(x));
                         int get2 = alpha.indexOf(subkey.charAt(x));

                         int total = (get1 + get2)%26;

                         sb += alpha.charAt(total);
                }
            return sb;

        }

         public static String AutoDecryption(String text,String key){
              int len = text.length();

              String current = key;
              String sb ="";

              for(int x=0;x<len;x++){
                 int get1 = alpha.indexOf(text.charAt(x));
                 int get2 = alpha.indexOf(current.charAt(x));

                 int total = (get1 - get2)%26;
                 total = (total<0)? total + 26 : total;
                 sb += alpha.charAt(total);

                 current += alpha.charAt(total);
              }
              return sb;
           }



}
```

Comment: Faiz, that message is telling you that there can only be one `main` method in your class.  Java starts with the `main` method when you run your program, so you need to decide which one is the method that you want to start with.  Maybe choose a different name for the other one.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I already choose a different name but it not change anything. Still got error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can there exist two main methods in a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399836/can-there-exist-two-main-methods-in-a-java-program)

Comment: *"error that main method already defined before.How to settle this error"* Don't define the same method twice. You have two `main` methods, exactly like the error says. Which of them would you expect to be called, and why, given that they are named the same and have the same parameters? Answer is "no idea", and that is exactly what the error is telling you too, i.e. that the system would have no idea what to do here, so fix it by removing/renaming one of them.

Answer (score 0):

JVM start executing java program from main() you could not defined more than one main() method in java error in 99 line please check code [see this](https://www.quora.com/Can-a-Java-program-contain-more-than-one-main-method-in-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the second main into another class if you really want everything in one file or have one of them have different arguments.

```
public class Sample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // do some stuff........
    }

}

class SampleClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // do some stuff........
    }
}
```

you could also do this:

```
public class Sample2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
         // do some stuff........
    }

    public static void main(byte b){    // whatever datatype you want
         // do some stuff........
    }

}
```