# How to compile 2 classes individually in one file in java?

Tags: java, oop

i was reading a book and it has an example which has 2 main methods in its file in different classes , one main method is for testing purposes but i cant understand a way to compile classes individually if there is any way please suggest me
here's the code

```
/**
 * @author achintya
 */
public class StaticTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Employee[] staff = new Employee[3];
        staff[0] = new Employee("tom",4000);
        staff[1] = new Employee("dick",60000);
        staff[2] = new Employee("harry",65000);

        for(Employee e : staff)
        {
            e.setId();
            System.out.println("name" + e.getName() + ",id=" + e.getId() + ",salary=" + e.getSalary());
        }
        int n = Employee.getNextId();
        System.out.println("next available id=" + n);
    }
}
class Employee
{
    private static int nextId = 1;
    private String name;
    private double salary;
    private int id;

    public Employee(String n,double s)
    {
        name = n;
        Salary = s;
        id = 0;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public double getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId()
    {
        id = nextId;
        nextId++;
    }
    public static int getNextId()
    {
        return nextId;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Employee e = new Employee("harry",50000);
        System.out.println(e.getName() + " " + e.getSalary());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short answer**: you can't compile individual classes.

**The long answer**:

You can still run the classes individually.

When you compile the file, you won't see any changes. However, java will compile 2 different classes, `StaticTest` in the `StaticTest.class` file, and `Employee` in the `Employee.class` file.

Then, to run `Employee.class`, just run `java Employee`, and the main method of `Employee` will run. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/27313798/13084867 for more

Here are the cmd commands. They can easily be replicated in a Linux environment:

```
C:\...\Folder> javac StaticTest.java
C:\...\Folder> java StaticTest
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have two classes in the same single source code file.
That is perfectly fair, as only **public** classes need to go into their own files. This means that you can have N non-public classes in the same source code file.

When things get compiled, there is no more notion of "coming out of the same .java file" though.

You end up with StaticTest.class *and* *Employee.class*. And the JVM simply allows you to also invoke a `main()` method on a non-public class.

But: there is simply no compiling the individual classes. The java compiler works on "file granularity". It will *always* compile the whole file you give to it, and there is no way for you to say: compile that file, but only the non-public class within.